# Dijkstra algorthim Stop working

Tags: c++, dijkstra, shortest-path, greedy

I am working on a project to find the shortest path to 50000 point in a 2d array(200*250). To make it simpler I only started with 2*2. 
From the points I can go N,W,E,S(without getting of the matrix)
I have 3 2d Arrays. 
Map[][]= it hold the binary values from 0-255
known[][]= either 0 or 1. 1 meaning it found the shortest path for the point. at the start all values are 0.
Dist[][]= the destination of the shortest path. At the start all value are 9999
I have three functions one is dijkstra().

```
 void dijkstra(){
 dist[0][0]=0;
 int i,j,counter=0;
 while(counter<=9){

    if(counter<9){
        cout<<"counter: "<<counter<<endl;
    }
    returnmin2(0,0);
    known[x][y]=1;

    returnS(x);
    returnN(x);
    returnE(y);
    returnW(y);

    if(s!=-1){
        if(known[s][y]==0){
            cost=sqrt(1+(pow((map[s][y]-map[s-1][y]),2.0)));
            cost1=cost+dist[s-1][y];

            if(cost1<dist[s][y]){
                dist[s][y]=cost1;
                path[s][y]=150;
                cout<<"Distance: "<<dist[s][y]<<endl;
            }
        }
    }

    if(n!=-1){
        if(known[n][y]==0){

            cost=sqrt(1+(pow((map[n][y]-map[x][y]),2.0)));
            cost1=cost+dist[n+1][y];

            if(cost1<dist[n][y]){
                dist[n][y]=cost1;
                path[n][y]=50;
                cout<<"Distance: "<<dist[x][y]<<endl;
            }
        }
    }

    if(e!=-1){
        if(known[x][e]==0){

            cost=sqrt(1+(pow((map[x][e]-map[x][e-1]),2.0)));
            cost1=cost+dist[x][e-1];

            if(cost1<dist[x][e]){
                dist[x][e]=cost1;
                path[x][e]=100;
                cout<<"Distance: "<<dist[x][w]<<endl;
            }
        }
    }

   if(w!=-1){
        if(known[x][w]==0){
            cost=sqrt(1+(pow((map[x][w]-map[x][w+1]),2.0)));
            cost1=cost+dist[x][w+1];

            float d= dist[x][w+1];
            if(cost1<dist[x][w]){
                dist[x][w]=cost1;
                path[x][w]=200;
                cout<<"Distance: "<<dist[x][w]<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    counter++;
}

}
```

the function`returnmin` find the smallest distance that is unknown.

```
float returnmin2(int i,int j){
    float min2,q=0;
    for(i;i<3;i++){
        for(j;j<3;j++){
            float q=dist[i][j];
            if((i==0) && (j==0)){
                min2=q;
                x=i;
                y=j;
            }
            if(q<min2){
                min2=q;
                x=i;
                y=j;
            }
        }
    }
    if(known[x][y]==0){
        x=x;
        y=y;
    }
    else if(known[x][y]!=0){
            if(y<2){
                returnmin2(x,y+1);
            }
            else {
                returnmin2(x+1,0);
            }

    }
}
```

returnS,N,W,E is a functions to tell which way we can go

```
int returnS(int v){
    if(v!=2){
        s=v+1;
    }
    else{
        s=-1;
    }
}
```

For some reason the program stop working when the counter come to 5. I am still now sure why. at the start it work fine. but for some reason when it get to point 2,2 it misses up. Please let me know if you want me to include the openfile function and main

Comment: What do you mean by "stop working"?  Have you tried stepping through your program in a debugger?

Comment: @paddy I dont really know how to do that. I will try to search it up. Any helpful links?

Comment: http://randu.org/tutorials/c/debug.php would be a good start.  Just quickly looking at your code, I expect you are indexing outside your arrays.  If your array dimensions are `[2][2]`, then valid indices are 0 and 1.  Also, you must be careful that things like `s-1` or `w+1` do not exceed the valid array indices.

Comment: @paddy yeah for the directions I have an if statment state if it went outside the matrix it will return s=-1 which then wont go through the if statement in dijkstra function. 
The code work fine until it get to a certain place then it break. it say .exe stopped working

Comment: You do realise that array indexing in C is _zero-based_, don't you?  So calling `returnS(1)` will create a value of `s` that is out-of-bounds.  Additionally, `returnS(-2)` and `returnS(3)` will also do that.  Even if the resulting `s` is 0, then indexing `s-1` will be out-of-bounds.  So your code might appear to work fine in other cases, but you're actually getting undefined behaviour.

Comment: @paddy
If I returnS(1) it will do the following:
V which is one in this case != 2:
Then s=v+1 meaning S=2; the point will be (x,2)
And S-1 will be (x,1) 
Which seem right to me.

Comment: If you say so.  I can't really do much more to convince you that it _won't be okay_.

Comment: Moreover, I think you should rebuild the algo for the general case, *then* apply it to a 2 x 2 matrix. E.g. another 2 variables *maxx* and *maxy* set at the beginning, then all the prog uses them instead of fixed values. And it will easier for us to help you.

Comment: Peculiar mix of specialization and abstraction. Specialized "returnS" function but duplicate code for the each directional test (`if (e!=-1) ...` is almost the same as `w!=-1` apart from a couple of values that'd be perfect function parameters).

Then you have function names with "return" in them, which `return` nothing.

We can't see all the code, don't know what n,s,e,w are or how they're used.

But lastly, your main djikstra function is already several times longer than the total amount of code in a typical djikstra or A* implementation.